# How to mute application that does not appears in Linux volume manager?

Tags: linux, audio

I've downloaded gitter application but I cannot find the option for muting the sound for all rooms. So I've decided to mute application using OS features instead of particular application. The problem is that I cannot see gitter application inside my volume control (as it is e.g. for VLC). I've found several command line solutions to this problem e.g. [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180612/script-to-mute-an-application) one. The problem wit this is that they rely on finding the pid of application inside the output of following command `pacmd list-sink-inputs` but gitter is not here. It's probably due to same reason that is not find inside volume control (the annoying beep just bees and stops not like VLC which is playing constantly). Can I somehow start process which will be muted?

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using? From "OS volume control" I assume you're using PulseAudio for sound?

Comment: Crunchbang, it is Debian based distro with OpenBox. By volume control I mean `pavucontrol` - A volume control for the PulseAudio sound server. Thank you.